# How to clear/reset git config commit.gpgsign to true

Tags: git, commit, gnupg

Hello Im trying to set true to git gpg config, but it have 2 values how do i remove the false value ?

```
abc@abc-ltmzmtx abc % git config --global commit.gpgsign true
abc@abc-ltmzmtx abc % git config --list | grep gpg           
commit.gpgsign=true
commit.gpgsign=false
```

Comment: The `false` setting must necessarily be local based on the above, so just remove the local setting entirely. You can use `git config --unset commit.gpgsign` or you can edit the `.git/config` file directly, or using `git config --edit`.